# azure webapp of windows service application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webapp2

I have an existing Windows Service application that can run as a service or as a console application.  It can be build x32 or x64.

It will by configuration file try to use a ip address and a port number.

Once it has that it will accept and send SOAP messages back and forth and service the requests.

The question is can this be deployed to Azure in a webapp framework, where scaling to meet increases in customer load is automatic.  If not what implementation would work, moving from what I have?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Apps (web sites) are not going to let you install a Windows Service, as that requires admin-level access to install.

You'd either need to run your Windows service in cloud services (web/worker roles, which are stateless Windows Server VMs) or Virtual Machines (where you have full VM access).

Alternatively, you'd need to extract your service code (pulling it out of the service shell) and run it in a different way. How you do this is up to you, but Web Apps provide certain features (such as Web Jobs) which may fit your model.